# Calculating resizing proportions

Tags: javascript, computational-geometry

I have a document of dimensions w and h.
Inside there is a rectangle of dimensions w1 and h1, positioned in coordinates x and y.

To compute x and y such that the rectangle will always be centered in the document I used:

```
x = (w / 2) - (w1 / 2)
y = (h / 2) - (h1 / 2)
```

and it works!

But I would also like to change w1 and h1 dynamically such that is always proportioned to w and h. For example, if the documents gets smaller than the rectangle, the rectangle should mantain its proportions while being scaled down.

So, how can I compute w1 and h1?

The "document" is the html5 canvas and the rectangle is an image. I'm working in javascript.

Thanks!

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/TkPX5/1/
Try to scale the window: the rectangle always stays in the center. But if the window gets smaller it doesn't resize. I miss the formula to compute w1 and h1.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have to fix the ratios of `w1` to `w` and `h1` to `h` anywhere in your code. You want `w1` and `h1` to be proportional to `w` and `h`, but the explicit factor has to be set by you. After that you can set e.g. `w1 = myFactor * w` (where `myFactor` is in range 0-1) so `w1` depends on the current value of `w`.

Comment: I would also like the original proportion between w1 and h1 to always be the same...

Comment: Make the constants `var WIDTH_PROPORTION = initialWidthOfImage / initialWidthOfDocument` and `var HEIGHT_PROPORTION = initialHeightOfImage / initialHeightOfDocument` and use these two as your factors. If you scale your document you get the new width of your image as `newWidth = WIDTH_PROPORTION * widthOfDocument` and the same for the height.

Comment: I hope you can take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/TkPX5/1/
The rectangle always stays in the center if you resize the window but... I would also like to scale it relatively!

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/HRS4w/2/ what you want to achieve?

Comment: Nope, cause the original proportion (300 / 400) goes lost as you resize. I already tried that by following your help and got that result. How can I keep the rectangle proportionated? Thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/HRS4w/2/ Now it should work :)

Comment: Thanks!! Why don't you post the fiddle as a question so I can upvote and mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code that should achieve what you want and is based on the jsfiddle that you provide in the comments:

```
var w1 = 300;
var h1 = 400;
var WPROP = w1/g.width;
var PROP = h1/w1;
g.draw = function() {       
    // DOCUMENT WIDTH AND HEIGHT
    var w = g.width;
    var h = g.height;            

    w1 = WPROP*w;
    h1 = PROP*w1;

    // RECTANGLE
    var x =  (w / 2) - (w1 / 2);
    var y = (h / 2) - (h1 / 2);

    g.ctx.fillRect(x,y,w1,h1);

}
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HRS4w/2) for this code in work.